# Benchmarking Rabbitmq Tool

Tags: rabbitmq, benchmarking

I have multiple components connected with RabbitMQ. Some are producers and consumers. I need to benchmark/load test my system. I need to ensure that the consumers can handle N messages/second. I've done some searching on the internet but haven't really found anything. Does anyone have any experience with benchmarking RabbitMQ? Ideally I'd like to just spam the network with messages without having to create a new producer.

Answer (score 6):

Do you know the tool [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)? With this tool you can simply simulate a heavy load on a server. I use it normaly for web applications, but i saw a [JMeter-RabbitMQ-plugin](https://github.com/jlavallee/JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP) to test AMQP message broker like RabbitMQ with JMeter. I think you should have a look on it.

If you have a web application in the front of RabbitMQ, then you can also test directly this application with JMeter.